# Filter by value from Db

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter

i need to filter all objects by some value from db for each object

**in models.py:**

```
class CurrencyLot(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    lot_status =models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

**in view.py:**

```
def currency_list(request):
    lot_list = Lot.objects.all().filter(lot_status=True).filter(stock__gte=???)
    return render(request, 'lots/list.html', {"lot_list":lot_list})
```

in need to fiter `stock__gte` by `order`for each object.

It is possible without `for` loop?

With `for` loop i may check this and `append` correct lots to new `lot_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to get this without for loop in Django

```
from django.db.models import F
Lot.objects.filter(lot_status=True,stock__gte=F('order'))
```

Comment: when i true to do this i recieved error :  Exception Value:  

global name 'min_order' is not defined

Comment: Now is problem that  it takes min order value from all object and filter all object to this value:) but not each object order to each object stock

Comment: @Hellbea Yes, updated the answer, this should definitely work.